# Text crossing more than max-width in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have set max-width to the div as 500px, but the text inside the div tag crossing the width and continuing instead of getting to next line.

Please help what code has to be changed.

Below is my code place:

div set to 500px

p tag containing text inside div. It crossing more than 500 px instead of getting to next line.

I know its little basic but i have no clue how to make it. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us your code (both html and css) and if you can make a JSfiddle for us than would that be nice to

Comment: Nothing you have described in your question works incorrectly: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/1LrLybp5/.  There must be something more to it.  Please edit your question with the original code or a demo on jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use css `word-wrap` so long text (links, long words etc) do not move outside your div.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

possible options are: `normal|break-word|initial|inherit`

You can also set `overflow:hidden` to prevent content that is going outside the boxes to be visible.

Comment: Your welcome @Guru, glad it works. If you like you can accept one of the answers so others know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No need to set a width on your paragraph tag. The width will be contained to the parent `<div>`.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/statzx2m/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a the [demo](http://codepen.io/tobaiasjl/pen/JYwGWZ)

Add this line to your css:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set to your paragraph a `word-wrap: break-word`:

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Example:

```css
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
}
.container > p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>LoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitametLoremsitamet</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ro3yfede/